# How do I do early return in ruby to reduce nested if?

Tags: ruby, coding-style, guard-clause

I always use early return to reduce nested if (programing with other languages) like this:

```c
//instead of nested if like this 
if (condition1) {
   if (condition2) {
     if (condition3) {
       //... finally meet all conditions 
       //do the job 
     }
   }
}
//return early 
if (!condition1) {
   //clean up resource in step #1
   return
}
if (!condition2) {
   //clean up resource in step #2
   return
}
if (!condition3) {
   //clean up resource in step #2
   return
}
...
//finally meet all conditions
```

But how do I do early return in ruby ? I can't return inside a if block in Ruby. I got the error

> "Uncaught exception: unexpected return ... `block (2 levels) in ': unexpected return (LocalJumpError)"

---- update -----

Sorry I forgot to mention that in a simple situation like this it works

```
def early(input)
  if (input <0)
    puts 'should >0'
    return
  end
  puts 'good'
end
```

I am learning Fiber and I use the sample from https://www.igvita.com/2010/03/22/untangling-evented-code-with-ruby-fibers/

```
def http_get(url)
  f = Fiber.current
  http = EventMachine::HttpRequest.new(url).get

  # resume fiber once http call is done
  http.callback { f.resume(1,http) }
  http.errback  { f.resume(2,http) }

  return Fiber.yield
end

EventMachine.run do
  Fiber.new{
    result = http_get('https://www.google.com/')
    if (result[0] ==2) 
      puts "error"
      return # using break has the error 'break from proc-closure (LocalJumpError)' too 
    end
    result = http_get('https://www.google.com/search?q=eventmachine')
    page = result[1]
    puts "Fetched page 2: #{page.response}"
  }.resume
end
```

I got the error.

---- update 2 ----

With the answer and comments I got I found this [How can I return something early from a block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518075/how-can-i-return-something-early-from-a-block)

And this [Why does the break statement in ruby behave differently when using Proc.new v. the ampersand sign?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888958/why-does-the-break-statement-in-ruby-behave-differently-when-using-proc-new-v-t) explains why break won't work either. To quote "break is supposed to make the caller of the block return, but Proc.new has already returned."

return vs break vs next is definitely an obstacle for a ruby newbie

Comment: “I can't return inside an `if` block in Ruby”—sure you can.

Comment: I got "Uncaught exception: unexpected return" now

Comment: Could you show the method you are having trouble with? Early return should normally work as long as you are in a method.

Comment: Also, I would say that `if`s are already a code smell, but _as many_ `if`s is a clear sign the code must be refactored ASAP.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Please see my update question.

Comment: @user000001 please see my update question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `next` instead of `return` to exit the inner block early:

```
class A 
  def run 
    yield
  end
end

a = A.new
a.run do 
  puts "ola"
  next
  puts "hello"
end
```

In order to use `return`, it should be place directly inside the method body.

But when you pass a block to a function, with `EventMachine.run do` and with `Fiber.new{`, the code inside the block is not directly inside the function, but is passed as a parameter to a different function. Inside the block you cannot call `return`, but you can exit early with `next`.

I am guessing that the reason the designers decided this is because a `return` inside the block would cause confusion whether the block would return, or the entire method.

Comment: Eh. How is it different from my answer?

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin: Unless I misunderstood, your answer suggests to use `tap`, mine doesn't

Comment: It does not matter whether it’s `tap`, `run`, or `foo`; what matters, blocks in ruby can be interrupted with `break`. Anyway.

Comment: Hi can you explain why break works while return not and when should I use one over the other ? I am learning ruby now and some grammars always seem odd to me (coming from C). Thanks!

Comment: BTW in my example break didn't work either, I got Uncaught exception: break from proc-closure
 /Users/qiulang/Dev/ruby-HW/fiber.rb:65:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/qiulang/Dev/ruby-HW/fiber.rb:65:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>': break from proc-closure (LocalJumpError)

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin break didn't work for my example either.

Comment: @Qiulang: `return` returns from the closest lexically enclosing method body. There is no method body enclosing your `return`. `next` returns from the closest lexically enclosing block. `break` returns from the closest lexically enclosing block and signals the method `yield`ing to the block to stop iterating. So, if you use a method like `Enumerable#each`, for example, `next` will skip to the next iteration and `break` will abort the iteration altogether.

Comment: So the reason I can't use break here is because there is no method wrap my Fiber.new block ?